# IOS long press does not have "save image" option when image is in a modal div

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, save, photo, long-press

Here's the example.

https://mariandioguardi.com/paintings/cat.asp?c=Not+So+%3Ci%3EStill+Life%3C%2Fi%3E

tap on a 300px image, you are shown a modal div with a 1200px image.   But long-press on that modal image only gives options "copy - look up - share..."

Question: how can I enable the save-image (to photos) option?

Right-clicking Works fine on Win-10 pc running Chrome or edge, but the long-press method fails on both ipad and iphone - both safari and chrome.  I am running IOS 13.2.3

I tried explicitly setting pointer-events to auto, but no difference.

Thanks!  jb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's because of these two things:

1. `#modal-outer` has `-webkit-touch-callout: none;`
2. `.modal-img` has `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.   However, (1) My web search cannot find any definition or reference to  -webkit-touch-callout ... Did you mean something else? ... and (2) I did say "I tried explicitly setting pointer-events to auto, but no difference." ...

Comment: You can read about `-webkit-touch-callout` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout). Both of the things I mentioned in my answer are—together—the cause of the problem, so doing *just* `pointer-events: auto;` wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: mmm, thanks Adam, ... but ...  Not clear what to do with that though, as of the 12 browsers evaluated on that page, only one - safari on IOS - supports this, and the page says "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future." ... Any other suggestions?

Comment: I understand that `-webkit-touch-callout` is non-standard. The point I'm trying to make is that the link you provided is currently set up so that `#modal-outer` is using `-webkit-touch-callout: none;`. If you remove that *and* if you remove `pointer-events: none;` from `.modal-img` then the problem goes away.

Comment: Yup, Adam, I think you've got it.  Thanks!  Cheers jb